# Redux Simple Router - Change state AND URL

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

Say I have some logic where the user has a list of options to choose from. When the user chooses an option, the app state and URL should reflect this choice. I have the URL routing figured out, but I wanted to be aware of the best strategy. Do I want use redux-simple-router pushPath AND dispatch an action? Does redux-simple-router have an API to change the state of the app directly through a route? Or would I handle the app state change somewhere else? Code is below:

```
    handleClick(value) {
        this.props.pushPath('/Options/' + value);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <div>Search bar here</div>
           <div className={styles.tile_container}>
             {this.state.options.map(option =>
               <div name= {option.name} key={option.key}  onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, option.name)}>{option.name}</div>
           )}
         </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: What type of state do you want to change? Is it related to a different reducer? Than i guess you have to dispatch the action.

Comment: App level state. User is configuring something (an 'Option') that will be created and saved in the backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I think about it, the path is just a coarse reflection of the UI state of the app. The *structure* of the UI triggers from the path, via React Router, but the *state* should be in Redux. I should be able to recover the UI state by typing in the same path, and the path should change in recognition of major changes of UI state.

So basically, you want to change the router when you want to set a "checkpoint" or reconfigure your layout, but you still need to `dispatch` actions to change the state of the Redux store.

Comment: That makes sense. The question is what's the best convention to dispatch action and change the URL? Should I call 'pushState' in the reducer? I was just wondering if there was a pattern to do this somewhat common task.

Comment: @capkutay Calling `pushState` in the reducer is the one thing you should definitely not do :) Reducers must be kept pure (free of side effects). Many other parts of Redux's architecture and ecosystem depend on this. Other than that, it's up to you. I'd suggest doing it in the flow of your async logic, wherever that happens to live (action creators, if you're using redux-thunk, as suggested in the guide).